# How can I retrieve a list of objects from database from a list of complex types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our domain model (and data model) contains a value type, LoanValueType. That type is unique for each loan. Ie, the two parts, LoanKey1 and LoanKey2 is together unique for each loan.

```
    loans.AddRange(
        _context.Loan
            .Include(x => x.Customer)
            .Include(x => x.Customer.Address)
            //...
            .Where(x => x.Status == ExampleStatus.Completed && x.ExampleDateTime > maxday)
            //...
            .Where(loan => loanIds.Any( x =>
                            x.LoanKey1 == loan.LoanValueType.LoanKey1 &&
                            x.LoanKey2 == loan.LoanValueType.LoanKey2))
        );
```

What we need is to get all loans from database that we have in a list, loanIds (List). It was earlier solved in a way that resulted in one by one call to the database which is not performant at all.

Though, the above query to database results in "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.". I do understand why, but cannot find a way to resolve that issue.

I tried to enumerate before the last where clause but it gives me a too big resultset. I only want to retrieve the loans in my list from database.

**EDIT:**

The loan value type is like this

```
public class LoanValueType
{
    public string LoanKey1 { get; private set; }

    public int? LoanKey2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `loanIds`?

Comment: if its a tricky select (or a complex select) you might consider getting that logic in a SP and call that to return the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var separator = "_"; // Consider making it more complex/unique
var loanIdsList = new List<string>();

foreach (var loanId in loanIds)
{
    loanIdsList.Add(loanId.LoanKey1 + separator + loanId.LoanKey2);
}

loans.AddRange(
    _context.Loan
        .Include(x => x.Customer)
        .Include(x => x.Customer.Address)
        //...
        .Where(x => x.Status == ExampleStatus.Completed && x.ExampleDateTime > maxday)
        //...
        .Where(loan => loanIdsList.Contains(loan.LoanValueType.LoanKey1 + separator + loan.LoanValueType.LoanKey2))
    );
```